# ASP.NET Core Ajax form post preventDefault doesn't get hit

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-core

I have a simple website (ASP.NET Core 2.2 MVC) with a _Layout that renders the body in its main tag:

```html
<main class="content">
    <div class="container-fluid p-0">

    <main role="main" class="pb-3">
    @RenderBody()
    </main>

    </div>
</main>
```

In the body (Index.cshtml) in one of the DIV elements I populate a list with a partialview:

```html
<div class="section-list">
    @{await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_PartialList1", Model);}
</div>
```

which lists some data as a table. Each row then has an edit option which open a modal form (via partialview). After clicking the edit row command a popup (modal) is shown that includes the following form:

```html
<form asp-controller="Home" asp-action="EditSpremljanje" method="post" data-ajax="true" data-ajax-method="post">

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Id: </label>
            <input class="form-control" asp-for="Id" readonly />
        </div>                   
    </div>
</div>

// a bunch of other labels & inputs ...

<div class="row" style="text-align: right">
    <div class="form-group col-md-12">

        <p class="text-left">Ali želite shraniti spremembe?</p>

        <label id="lbErrorMessage" style="color:red"></label>

        <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-warning" data-dismiss="modal">Prekliči</button>

        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary ml-2">Shrani</button>
    </div>
</div>
</form>
```

The problem is that when I submit the form (hit ENTER on my keyboard or click the submit button) the jQuery code (in Index.cshtml) below doesn't get hit.

```html
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.content').on('submit', 'form', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();

    $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: '/Home/EditSpremljanje',
        data: $('form').serialize(),
        success: function () {
            //alert('form was submitted');
        }
        }).done(function (result) {

            if (result.status === "success") {
                $('#modalGeneric').modal('hide');

                //reload data - partial list
                 $('.section-list').load(url, {
                searchString: '', pageNumber: 1, idSelect: 0
            });
            } else {
                $('#lbErrorMessage').html(result.message);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

The form gets posted though, because the 'IActionResult EditSpremljanje' in my Controller gets hit.

Comment: The modal (with the form), is likely being embedded in the HTML outside of `.content`, so that is not working as a delegate. Try temporarily changing it to `$(document).on('submit', 'form', ...)` and see what happens. If it works, then you either need to ensure that the modal HTML is inside `.content`, or choose a different delegate.

Comment: yes, my modal was outside of `.content`. Thank you!!!